# Excel For/Next using Array Elements

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My end result is this:  I want to programmatically select tabs in a workbook using specific criteria found on each tab.  My tabs' names can change.

I've tried using the Sheets(Array(tab1,tab2,tabx)).select function by building the items within the Array as a variable but receive a subscript out of range error when using it.
I'm hoping the answer is easier than I'm imagining.
Thank you.
This is the code I'm playing with:

```
Sub SelectTabs()

Dim intX As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intArray() As Integer
ReDim intArray(1)

For intX = 6 To 25
    If ((intX / 2) - Int(intX / 2) = 0) And intX > 5 And intX < 25 Then
        Sheets(intX).Select
        ws_name = Sheets(intX).Name
        If (Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_01").Value & Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_02").Value & _
            Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_03").Value & Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_04").Value & _
            Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_05").Value & Range("Test" & Range("C29").Value & "_06").Value) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve intArray(UBound(intArray) + 1)
            If Tabs = "" Then
                Tabs = ws_name
            Else
                Tabs = Tabs & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & ws_name
            End If
            intArray(UBound(intArray)) = intX
            'intArray(intX) = ws_name
        End If
    End If
Next intX
Sheets(Array(intArray)).Select
```

End Sub

Comment: try `Sheets(intArray).Select`

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question [Excel macro is acting differently on two computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646418/excel-macro-is-acting-differently-on-two-computers/38647021#38647021)

Basically, after you select the first sheet you select the rest with .Select Replace:=False

```
Sheets(1).Select True
Sheets(2).Select False
Sheets(3).Select False
....
```

[Worksheet.Select Method (Excel) - MSDN - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194988.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.. but its the progression that is difficult.  There are 10 sheets out of 30 to choose from, Only some should be selected.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you select each sheet before you check them. You can replace `Sheets(Array(intArray)).Select` with `Sheets( Split( Tabs, """,""" ) ).Select`

Comment: Perfect Slai, thank you... I'll have to read up on the split command.